# Why can duplicate questions be voted upon?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, voting

From what I know, duplicate questions are just there so that future visitors can find the original question faster through search engines. But then why can they be voted upon?

The only quality that can exist in a duplicate question is the title, so is the voting done according to the title? Voting upon a duplicate question on the basis of titles is just unfair, it judges the grammar capabilities, and why are we judging grammar in a coding related site? Bad grammar questions in general should be given suggestions or edited instead of being downvoted, so titles surely aren't the basis of voting.

What's the basis of voting in duplicate questions? And is the votability of duplicate questions good or bad? Downvoting may reduce the accessibility of the question. Upvoting may unfairly make it overly more accessible.

Comment: There are good duplicates and there are bad duplicates. Good ones help find the original better and are more useful. Looks like this usefulness can be expressed with voting. _“The only quality that can exist in a duplicate question is the title”_ — search engines look at more than just the title. Not sure how grammar is relevant here.

Comment: @SebastianSimon But what makes a duplicate bad or good? That's partly what I am looking for.

Comment: It can be an awesome sign post due to its wording / phrases / context. That deserve upvotes. If it is just a repeat / rerun a down vote is warranted as that is not useful.

Comment: Upvoting is basically saying that "I found this useful". If you find the duplicate question to be a good signpost then by all means give it an upvote. Also downvotes on duplicate questions is a criteria that the [Roomba script](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) takes into account before deleting some questions

Answer (score 12):

Voting on questions is based on whether they show research effort, and whether they're useful and clear. Duplicate questions are just questions and I think they should be allowed to be voted upon, just like any other question.

If a duplicate question helps in finding a canonical, that's certainly useful, and possibly worth an upvote. Some duplicates are more helpful than others, because they have better titles, better terms in the body, etc, and votes are the ideal way to signal that helpfulness. Note that voting on a question *solely* because of the quality of the title is perfectly reasonable.

If a question is poorly asked, or has exactly the same terms as the canonical, or doesn't show any effort from the OP, that's a poor question, and downvotes are a good way to signal that. Again, voting just on the title is fine.

In general, I've found that whether a question is a duplicate, and whether I vote on it, is somewhat orthogonal. I've definitely closed questions as duplicates that I've then downvoted in some cases and upvoted in others.

Comment: So the basis is weather it helps to find the original question and how mush research effort has been shown?

Comment: @ShambhavGautam Partly, yes, but also the question itself could be useful because it asks the same thing in a slightly different way than the canonical. Basically, I'd suggest not getting hung up on whether a question is a duplicate, when deciding whether/how to vote upon it. Just treat it like you would any other question.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say "better titles, better terms" because that would imply that using same phrases can be added to the original duplicate. Main purpose of good duplicates are being different questions - or that they phrase problem in different way.